# What are the current numbers of Russian refugees and asylum seekers?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, asylum

[Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_emigration_following_the_2022_invasion_of_Ukraine):

> Following the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine, more than 300,000 Russian citizens and residents are estimated to have left Russia by mid-March 2022 as political refugees and economic migrants, due to a desire to evade criminal prosecution for exercising free speech regarding the invasion.

I am looking for the recent numbers of Russians who moved out of Russia since the invasion, both total and those who requested asylum, by country. I am also interested in the policies various countries adopted towards Russian refugees, by country (e.g., some European countries suspended flights to Russia and even cancelled visas for Russians, while Turkey, on the other hand, has allowed visa-free entry for Russian citizens.)

---

Related question: [What does Ukraine gain by having Western countries ban all Russian visa?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/74741/38304)

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to look for how educated current Russian emigrants are or from where in Russia or which age, if that information is available.

Answer (score 2):

More than 820.000 according to this study https://re-russia.net/en/review/347/

Comment: This is relevant, but I suggest that you expand this into a full answer, e.g., quoting a paragraph from the article and/or including the image of the table in it. Otherwise it risks to be deleted as "link-only answer".