# Why did Poland, Finland and some other EU countries ban Russian citizens from entering?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, visa

I was surprised to learn that Estonia, Czechia, Finland, Poland, Latvia and Lithuania [banned Russian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Russian_citizens) from entering for tourism purposes. What are the practical reasons for doing so? Or was it primarily done as a symbolic gesture of no practical meaning?

It's probably not due to fear of Russian special agents entering those countries, as it would be quite easy for an FSB agent to bypass these restrictions.

Comment: Probably even more related https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75139/why-did-the-eu-suspend-the-2007-visa-facilitation-agreement-with-russia-if-it-d There people wondered why they'd do that if didn't cover tourism. (Part of the answer was that it was going to make covering tourism easier as well.,) Also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74741/what-does-ukraine-gain-by-having-western-countries-ban-all-russian-visa

Answer (score 23):

As you can read in a [related Q&A](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74741/what-does-ukraine-gain-by-having-western-countries-ban-all-russian-visa) Zelensky did seemingly aks for this. So that could be one reason. Another reason discussed in answers there is that tourist visas may be seen by some as "luxury goods", so simply a way to sanction Russia[ns]. As one British (somewhat right wing) journalist [put it](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/the-west-should-turn-away-all-russian-tourists-ptkgd67xj)

> How much longer should Russians be able to frolic on European holidays? Estonia’s prime minister, Kaja Kallas, says “visiting Europe is a privilege, not a human right”.

And some Russians seemingly didn't think twice about Z-symbols on their vehicles, [when](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g19jdzG19SY) travelling to neighboring countries.

Third, in some of those countries you've mentioned [it seems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/75140/18373) the topic was becoming political football, internally, and several of those countries were going to have elections at about the same time frame.

I managed to find a poll on this, from Sep 2022. [Reportedly](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2022/09/22/finland-set-to-limit-or-stop-entry-of-russian-tourists-a78863) around 70% of Finns then supported the move "to stop issuing tourist visas to Russians".

---

Even in countries that were less politically inclined to sanction Russia[ns] as such, like in Armenia, there [were](https://jam-news.net/second-influx-of-russians-into-armenia-risks-for-a-small-country/) concerns that the large 2nd wave of Russians (mostly draft dodgers--arriving on whatever travel arrangements they can) would have some disturbing impact on the local socioeconomic balance, e.g. by driving up rents. A similar [story](https://eurasianet.org/the-septembrists-russias-latest-wave-of-emigres-to-georgia) plays out in Georgia:

> Many Georgians direct their ire not at the Russians but rather toward their own government, which has maintained a laissez faire approach to the mass influx. The government’s policy has long been oriented toward a normalization of ties with Russia via trade and tourism.  [...] Faced with such criticism, the authorities have been trying to play down the volume and the impact of the Russian arrivals. Political opposition figures, meanwhile, are doing the opposite.

[According](https://georgiatoday.ge/ndi-69-of-respondents-believe-that-georgia-should-introduce-visa-regime-for-russians/) to some local polling firm, some 69% of Georgians support a re-introduction of visas for Russians.

Even *The Economist* which is usually pro-immigration, and ultimately argues that Russian draft dodgers should be welcomed to Europe, has commentary [like](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/09/30/europeans-should-welcome-russian-draft-dodgers)

> Among large European countries only Germany and France have so far indicated that they are willing to let [draft dodging] Russians in. To get there, however, most would have to cross borders with the Baltic states and Finland. These countries are a lot less keen.
>
> They—and others—have reasonable excuses. Poland has already accommodated millions of Ukrainian refugees. Russia’s neighbours, including the tiny Baltic states, Estonia, Latvia and Lithuania, have bitter experience of being ruled from Moscow and remain under constant threat from Mr Putin, who claims a right to “protect” ethnic Russians in neighbouring states. Estonia and Latvia have substantial Russian-speaking minorities, so adding a large influx of young Russian men understandably makes them nervous. You can see why they refuse to open their borders—though they might consider letting draft-dodgers pass through en route to the rest of the EU.

I know you're technically asking just about tourists, but the issues have certainly become intermingled since the "partial" Russian mobilization of last fall.
Here's a semi-funny [story](https://www.dw.com/en/escape-from-conscription-russian-draft-evaders-in-germany/a-64201722) relating to that point, about a Russian who ultimately went to Germany, first by crossing into Kazahstan, and even though no visa is technically needed for that step:

> "The Kazakh [border] official asked with a grin where we were going. We'd made up a story beforehand: we were going to the mountains to see the snow. The border guard started laughing and we laughed too," he said. [...] Then Ilya flew to Cologne, where he applied for asylum.

Comment: Strangely enough, places as far as Bali are now looking to tighen their visas for Russians https://srnnews.com/indonesias-bali-wants-to-tighten-visa-requirements-for-russian-tourists/

Comment: what is a Z-symbol?

Comment: @whoisit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_(military_symbol)

Comment: If I recall correctly, shortly before Finland and Estonia closed their land borders, Russian travel agencies started selling vacation packages to Spain/Greece via these countries. Hundreds of buses of not-so-wealthy travelers who later board a charter flight in, e.g., the rather small Tallinn airport, would present many problems even without any of the other reasons mentioned here.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава That's very unfortunate for UVA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_Society

Answer (score 18):

The point is to tie responsibility to privilege.

There is a disconnect in Russian society that one is not responsibile for the acts of the government. If you have no choice in who rules you, then you do not share accountability for its policies.

The EU members reject this mindset. In their mind, Russian citizens are ultimately responsible for the acts of their government, even if they do not have democratic means to select it. Every Russian who is vacationing in Europe while the war rages on in Ukraine should be protesting in Russia, and if they do not care, then Europe will force them to confront their civic responsibility by sending them back.

In short, the privilege of accessing the pleasures of democratic world is tied to the responsibility of upholding the basic principles of democratic world order.

Comment: Right, why wouldn't someone protest against Putin in a possibly futile attempt to change the government? I [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Alexei_Navalny?wprov=sfla1) [think of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Sergei_and_Yulia_Skripal#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DOn_4_March_2018%2C_Sergei%2Cthe_city_of_Salisbury%2C_England.?wprov=sfla1) [any](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/world/2022/sep/22/russia-protests-more-than-1300-arrested-at-anti-war-demonstrations-ukraine) [reason](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/10/20/russian-police-are-torturing-anti-war-activists).

Comment: That's *assuming* that we accept the implicit argument that "protesting against Putin's invasion of Ukraine" and "never leaving Russia" are equivalent, which is trivially untrue on the face of it.

Comment: Also, you make a statement about what "the EU members" are doing and think, but note that as indicated in the question, only a minority of EU members (almost all smaller nations that are close to Russia) are actually doing it.

Comment: +1. However, blaming the Russians for not protesting the regime is tantamount to blaming the Auschwitz concentration camp prisoners for not knocking down the guards and freeing themselves: if they all attempted it together, they would have arguably succeeded even though a few would have been shot.

Comment: @Greendrake You genuinely think concentration camps are countries and their prisoners are citizens? You think that is an accurate comparison? I mean really consider your response before swiping your keyboard.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut The comparison is not intended to be accurate but just to show the principles: 1) Protest alone and get imprisoned / tortured / killed (depending where it happens). 2) There's no way to ensure that all protest together.

Comment: @Greendrake "blaming the Russians for not protesting the regime" Sure open protest is dangerous but that doesn't mean that there aren't other forms of protest available. Not supporting the regime as far as possible or fleeing if possible are a good start. If I were a Russian, I'd either not live in Russia anymore or I would try to work only the absolute minimum possible to survive and surely not in the military industry for example.

Comment: @Trilarion - Fleeing...you mean, like by going to another country as a tourist and then soliciting refugee status or permanent residency? That seems unlikely to work under the system that this answer lauds.

Comment: @Obie2.0 First, I would probably have left Russia, would I have lived there, in 2014 and not only now and secondly there are still lots of ways to flee and request asylum. Does this answer really hinder people from fleeing? That's another question.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Are you not mixing two very different things here? This question is about banning tourist visas, whereas leaving your country because you are persecuted functions through asking for asylum. A tourist trip is a luxury good, and by definition involves voluntarily going back to your home country. I have yet to see anybody here asking for Russian asylum seekers to be turned away.

Comment: @Frodyne - Getting asylum is not always easy, which is why many people—not just from Russia, but all over–opt to enter on a tourist visa or even illegally and then solicit it. Since Trilarion mentioned asylum, that element is pertinent. As to no one wanting to turn away asylum seekers—see the current top answer.

Comment: As to whether tourism is a luxury, that depends on whether one thinks free movement between countries should be a luxury. Some people think it is, while [others think it is the expression of a fundamental human right](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/jul/26/border-free-world-better-hostile-immigration-policies).

Comment: Solid answer, entry into a foreign country *for leisure purposes*, is a privilege, not a right.  However, I would qualify the "requirement to protest" a bit - Russia is not like protesting against the Iraq War in 2003.  Or comfortably typing an answer in SE.Po in a democratic country.  Protests may very well land you in a nasty jail, and from there possibly to the front later on.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Is it such a solid answer? It gives the impression that it is talking about some reasoning in Europe in general, but most European countries do not have the policy under discussion. It suggests that the policy is meant to motivate opposition to Putin—which may be correct—but then posits an implausible argument for how it would work (protest and travel are mutually exclusive, so anyone who is traveling should be sent back to protest) instead of the more plausible one (people who are discontented with sanctions may be motivated to oppose the war).

Comment: It also promotes an idea that is dangerously close to blaming the victim by saying that people under autocratic governments (except in Hong Kong, possibly) *should* be blamed for the actions of their government because they should be presumed not to be risking their safety by openly defying it. I would point out that this is very similar to how conservative politicians in the Americas treat immigration—"If their country is so bad, why don't they go back and fix it?"

Comment: @Obie2.0 It's a solid answer *re. the motivation of the countries in question*, regardless of whether I agree or not it will make much difference or is a good idea. I agree w you, and qualified, re. the expectation for protests.  But, no, not at all impressed with the 70% support.  While I not go out of my way to ask my country to bar Russian *tourists*, I would also not lose much sleep if they chose that course of action.  Re. your claim of fundamental human right, that's verrrry debatable considering how much emissions a *small* proportion of ppl, even in rich countries, contribute flying.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - I think it is important not to conflate the right of freedom of movement and restrictions upon it, such as borders and visas, with whether particular modalities of movement are equally fundamental rights. People can and do also travel between countries with cars, buses, trains, boats, bicycles, horses, their feet, and so forth, and even planes have the potential to [be developed to pollute less.](https://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a41453056/eviation-electric-aircraft/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Neither average Ivan neither average Natasha can afford traveling abroad.
   Traveling costs are far away from what general public can afford. Exceptions may be in Moscow and St. Petersburg (former, maybe reinstated-to-be Leningrad). Those who can afford paying the traveling costs are those quite far above the average and getting there was for some costs - they needed to prove their loyalty to the grand ruler.
   Banning the loyals will annoy the loyals. The poor ones won't be annoyed because they are not to lose any of their limited options.
2. Russia is well-known for their intensive intelligence activities.
   Russian tourists and business visitors are quite renowned to be potential Russian spies. After last incidents the Russian embassies round Europe were quite depopulated.
   Banning potential spy income helps the home intelligence by off-loading the new suspects so they can focus on the settled ones.

Comment: ~5 millions Russian tourists visit Turkey every year, and ~1 million visit Egypt (numbers are not secret, everyone can google), more countries and numbers one can find e.g. in https://russtd.com/statistics-of-russian-outbound-tourism-for-2018.html. Visiting Poland, Czechia, Baltic countries was even more affordable - weekend in 3* hotel or AirBNB apartments and low-coster flight (or even a bus) were cheaper than a week or two in Turkey. Average Ivan & Natasha definitely can afford this, especially when they do not have children yet.

Comment: *getting there was for some costs - they needed to prove their loyalty to the grand ruler* => this is nonsense, many middle and upper class people made their money without having any government connections. It’s not North Korea we’re talking about here.

Comment: @JonathanReez There’s a difference between having government connections, and actively avoiding being viewed as a threat by the government. Most upper class Russians _have_ made an active effort to not antagonize the regime, even if they have no connections to it.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn this applies to citizens of every authoritarian regime out there, not just Russia. 99% of people are not willing to risk going to jail in order to depose the current regime. It's silly to single out Russians and not ban (say) Chinese, Iranian, Saudi, Venezuelan, or Ethiopian citizens. Sorry but "must be willing to die in jail to fight against the regime" is a ridiculous standard. Navalny is currently doing it but he's exceptionally brave.

Comment: @Victor - The problem that you are running into there is twofold. First, if we take all the data from that page as representing one trip per person, we already are looking at only about a third of the population traveling, or less than half, so the argument that the average person does not travel abroad is already defensible. Second, and far more important, there is a serious risk of multiple counting there, because that represents the *number of trips*, and many people take multiple trips, particularly in cases of commuting near borders and so forth.

Comment: Notice how few trips were for purposes of tourism. Non-tourist trips are likely to be things like be transportation of goods, visiting family members, and commuting that are likely to have a high trip-per-person ratio. Indeed, Meduza suggests that [fewer than a quarter of Russian people](https://www.google.com/amp/s/meduza.io/amp/en/news/2022/09/20/russian-public-opinion-research-center-77-of-russians-have-not-been-abroad-in-the-past-five-years) had traveled to other countries in the five years previous to the war.

Comment: The answer may exaggerate how difficult it is, but it seems reasonable to say that touristic travel abroad—and particularly travel to Western Europe or further-flung regions—was largely limited to a somewhat more prosperous segment of the population.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Meduza reinterprets (and gives no link to) results of sociological research done 11.09.2022 by https://wciom.ru/ via phone calls to 1600 people 18+. Other research by the same organisation https://wciom.ru/analytical-reviews/analiticheskii-obzor/letnie-plany-2020-dom-dacha-i-vnutrennij-turizm shows that ~40-50% of respondents give "no money" as the reason of staying at home in the summer. My point is that "who can afford paying the traveling costs are those quite far above the average" is exaggerated and leads to wrong "they needed to prove their loyalty to the grand ruler".

Comment: @Victor - That same source says only 13% of people traveled internationally. The percentage you give should be the number of people who did not travel even *domestically* and *admitted* it was because of lack of money.